# How to order by date documents in aggregator with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregator

I have this aggregators to deduplicate documents :

```
   $searchParams['body'] = [
        'aggs' => [
            'dedup' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field' => 'source',
                    'size' => 50,
                    'order' => [
                        'max_hits' => "desc"
                    ]
                ],
                'aggs' => [
                    'dedup_hits' => [
                        'top_hits' => [
                            'size' => 1
                        ]
                    ],
                    'max_hits' => [
                        'max' => [
                            "script" => "doc.score"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

This query order by document score. However, i want to order by _timestamp field. It's possible ? I have test with Date Histogram aggregator. But without success.

Comment: It's possible to use Date Histogram in terms order ?

Comment: no i don't have this work at the moment